# Laravel sub-folder installation creates issue with redirection

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I have installed Laravel app in subfolder. The URL is like: `mysite.com/laravel/public/index.php/home`

It is working fine, but when I click on the menu items like `/name`, it is redirecting me back to home `mysite.com` but I want it to be like `mysite.com/laravel/public/index.php/name`

Laravel's own default routes, like `{{ route('register') }}` is working fine from anywhere I test but my own defined routes are not working.

How can I fix it? I have searched it but got nothing. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: could you share your directory structure, htaccess, and the `/name` thingy -- is it a folder, a route, or something else?

Comment: /name is route, eg: <a href="/name" class="nav-link">Name</a>

Comment: The directory and .htaccess file are inLaravel default structure

Comment: Have you changed the APP_URL in the ,env file?

Comment: really, i wish that you could share the directory structure, the content of the `.htaccess`, and the `routes.php` registry for your `/name`.. to help more people understanding the root cause of this trouble..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you installed Laravel in subfolder, you path for /home should be:

```
mysite.com/laravel/public/home
```

When you are defining routes, your /name still should be defined as:

```
Route::get('/name', 'Controller@function');
```

Linking from Blade when Laravel is installed in subfolder might get a bit tricky:

```
{{ URL::to('/') }}/name
```

Comment: actually, doing `{{ URL::to('/') }}/name` is pretty bad, why not, `{{ route('name') }}` if you have registered the route as `Route::get('/name', 'Controller@function')->name('name');` as it is much cleaner.. please check on the [named routes documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes).

Comment: I am using {{ URL::to('/home') }} instead of {{ URL::to('/') }}/name. It is working now. thank you